# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'any[]'. in angular2

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DropDownService } from './service/drop-down.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppResolve implements Resolve<any[]> {
   constructor(private dropDownService: DropDownService) { }
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.dropDownService.getDropDown();
   }
}
```

Return method is giving error:

> Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Property
>   '_isScalar' is missing in type 'any[]'.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>`. You seem to be returning `any` here.

Comment: what should I return

Comment: @rajm I am getting the same error.